# WPF - How to close a file that was opened in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

On a click event of a button , I'm opening a file in [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview) of a `WPF` app as follows. I've another button for closing the file but need to figure out how to close that opened file after reading it but without exiting my entire WPF app.

Think of it as a scenario similar to what we have in `Microsoft WORD` application where you can open a WORD document by using `File-->Open` menu item, and then you can close it by using `File-->Close` menu item while keeping the WORD application still open with top Ribbon. In my case, I've a toolbar on top with open and close button that I need to perform similar Open/Close file operations on:

```
private void BtnOpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Filter = "Rich Text Format (*.rtf)|*.rtf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open);
        TextRange range = new TextRange(mainRTB.Document.ContentStart, mainRTB.Document.ContentEnd);
        range.Load(fileStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
}
```

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. What have you tried? Just to give you a hint: Once you release your FileStream resource (that is disposable) it will look like you "closed" the file. Furthermore, what's the real problem? If you want to "close" the file, wouldn't be sufficient to clear the RichTextBox and dispose your resources?

Comment: `filestream.Close()` will close it.  You should probably also `Dispose()` it, or better yet, wrap it in a `using`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner You mean wrapping in `using` will take care of both `.Close()` and `Dispose()` correct?

Comment: @nam Yes.  It will even close/dispose the stream if there is an error thrown while reading it.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Actually the following last line of your comment was the solution (thank you): `wouldn't be sufficient to clear the RichTextBox and dispose your resources?` If you like you can convert your comment into a `Reply` and I'll mark it a an `answer` so others can benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "close" the file whose content is shown in a RichTextBox, I think it'd be enough to clear the RichTextBox and to dispose your resources.

By "disposing your resources", I mean closing your `FileStream` or wrap it in a `using`, for example.